# Sum equals the product

Tags: number-theory

A while ago, just playing with some numbers I noticed that $1+2+3=1\cdot2\cdot3$, so I started thinking about the non-zero integer solutions of the equation

$$\prod_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$

For example, for $n=2$, the only solution is the pair $(2,2)$, for $n=3$ the only solutions are $(1,2,3)$ and $(-1,-2,-3)$ and that's what I have by now, the problem is, I solved the case $n=2$ using divisibility and the case $n=3$ I proved that if $|a_1|\leq|a_2|\leq|a_3|$, then for $a_2>2$ there was no solution, so I just analyzed every case. Can someone help me with the general case?

Comment: here is a nice pdf about this https://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~anow/ps-dvi/si-krl-a.pdf

Comment: also read this  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270185488_When_Does_a_Sum_of_Positive_Integers_Equal_Their_Product

Comment: I was going to make a few basic observations.  But that pdf covers them all.  I'll just add: you state "If $|a_1| \le |a_2| \le |a_3|....$.  Since addition and multiplication are commutative you can arrange them in order of size and without loss of generality you can assume that $this is always true.

Comment: @DeepeshMeena The link seems to be dead.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776443/8530

Comment: @MaximeJaccon since the OP has been inactive for some time, I would like to ask you to clarify what exactly you are asking for. Is it the "general case", $n=3$ case? Are you looking for the no. of solutions or parametrizations, if any?

Answer (score 8):

This answer is partial. It concerns mainly natural solutions of the equation

The brief search showed several related papers, which I listed below as the references. Unfortunately, I had no time to study them all, so my survey below is incomplete.

It seems that all of these references concern natural solutions of the equation.
So let $a(n)$ be the number of all nondecreasing natural solutions.
To avoid the trivial case we assume that $n\ge 1$.

For each natural $n$ the equation has a natural solution $(1,\dots,1,2,n)$ [Theorem 2, KN], so $a(n)\ge 1$. On the other hand, $a(n)\le n^n$, see [EN].

All nondecreasing natural solutions are listed for $n\le 5$ in the proof of Theorem 1 from [KN], for $n\le 7$ in the solution of Problem 2.14 from [ML] and before, for $n\le 12$ in Table 1 from [Eck], and for $n=50$ and $n=100$ in [KN, p.4].

The numbers $a(n)$ for all natural $n\le 100$ are listed in [KN]:

[image]

Also is known that $a(1997) = 20$, $a(1998) = 8$, $a(1999) = 16$, and $a(2000) = 10$ [KN].

Thus, the value of $a(n)$ varies.

It can be arbitrary large. Indeed, pick any natural $s$. Then for $n=2^{2s}+1$, the equation has $s+1$ nondecreasing natural solutions, namely, $(1,\dots,1, 2^j+1, 2^{2s-j})$, where $j\le s$ is any nonnegative integer [Ser, 175].

On the other hand, it can be just $1$. In this case the number $n$ is called *exceptional* [Eck]. The
set of exceptional $n\le 10^{10}$ is $\{2,3,4,6,24, 114, 174, 444\}$ and is unknown whether there exists other exceptional $n$, see [Eck]. On the other hand, if $n>6$ is exceptional then $n-1$ is prime and $n$ equals $0$, $24$, $30$, $84$, $90$, $114$, $150$ or $174$ modulo $210$, see [KN, Theorem 9 and p.5].

On the third hand, for some natural $n$ the number of *all* nonzero solutions of the equation can be infinite. Namely, when $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$, and the sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ contains $(n-1)/2$ numbers $1$ and $(n-1)/2$ numbers $-1$, then the remaining number from the sequence can be arbitrary nonzero integer. We call these solutions *special*.

On the fourth hand, we can bound the number of *all* nonzero nonspecial solutions of the equation
for any natural $n$ as follows.

**Proposition.** For any natural number $n$ the equation has at most $n(2n)^{n-1}$ nonzero nonspecial integer solutions.

*Proof*. Let $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ be any solution of the equation. Suppose that $\max_{1\le i\le n} |a_i|$ is attained for some natural $i\le n$. For the sake of simplicity assume that $i=n$. Then $\left| \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j\right|\le |a_n|n$, so $\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} |a_j|\le n$. It follows $|a_j|\le n$ for each natural $j\le n-1$, so there are at most $(2n)^{n-1}$ choices for the sequence $(a_j)_{j=1}^{n-1}$. When this sequence is chosen, there remains at most one choice for $a_n$, but the case
when the coefficients at $a_n^1$  and $a_n^0$ it cancel. The latter holds iff $\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j=1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j=0$. This holds iff $a_i=\pm 1$ for each natural $i\le n-1$, $n-1$ is even,  exactly a half of numbers from the sequence $(a_j)_{j=1}^{n-1}$ equal $1$, and $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}=1$. Then
$n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and the solution $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is special. $\square$

*References*

[Eck] Michael W. Ecker, *[When Does a Sum of Positive Integers Equal Their Product?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270185488_When_Does_a_Sum_of_Positive_Integers_Equal_Their_Product)*, Mathematics Magazine **75**:1 (Feb 2002).

[EN] C.D. Evans, M.A. Nyblom, *[An Algorithm to Solve the Equal-Sum-Product Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3874)*.

[KN] Leo Kurlandchik, Andrzej Nowicki, *[When the sum equals the product](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261822936_When_the_Sum_Equals_the_Product)* ([JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3621488)), The Mathematical Gazette **84(499)** 91--94. (This is the paper at the dead [link](https://www-users.mat.umk.pl/%7Eanow/ps-dvi/si-krl-a.pdf) from Deepesh Meena's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919430/sum-equals-the-product#comment6030929_2919430)).

[Man] barak manos et al., *[A finite sequence of natural numbers, whose sum equal its product:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849835/a-finite-sequence-of-natural-numbers-whose-sum-equal-its-product)*, Mathematics StackExchange.

[ML] *[Equal Sum-Product Problem](https://public.websites.umich.edu/%7Emichiganlemma/material/2020/PowerRound_Solutions.pdf)*,
Michigan Lemma 2020.

[Ser] W. Sierpi'nski, *Number Theory*, Part II, (in Polish), PWN, Warszawa 1959.

[Zak] Maciej Zakarczemny, *[On the equal sum and product problem](http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/ojs/index.php/amuc/article/download/1662/906/)*,
Acta Math. Univ. Comenianae **XC**:4 (2021) 387-402.

[Zak2] Maciej Zakarczemny, *[Equal-Sum-Product problem II](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/abs/equalsumproduct-problem-ii/5A5B79FDCB28A1E83D96DD6BA9147FE2#)*, Canadian Mathematical Bulletin, First View, 1-11.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer.

We want to find all the non-zero integer solutions of $\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j$ for $n\ge 2$.

This answer is only interested in the solution $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ satisfying $|a_1|\le |a_2|\le \cdots \le|a_n|$. If $a_j=-a_{j+1}$, then this answer is only interested in $(a_j,a_{j+1})$ satisfying $a_j\lt a_{j+1}$.
(For example, for $n=4$, this answer is interested in $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(\color{red}{-1},\color{red}1,-2,-2)$, not $(\color{red}1,\color{red}{-1},-2,-2)$.)

This answer proves the following claims :

**Claim 1** : If $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then the equation has infinitely many non-zero integer solutions.

**Claim 2** : If $n\not\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then the equation has only finitely many non-zero integer solutions.

**Claim 3** : If $n\ge 3$, then the equation has at least one non-zero integer solutions where at least one $a_i$ is negative.

**Claim 4** : If $n=2$, the only non-zero integer solution of the equation is $(a_1,a_2)=(2,2)$.

**Claim 5** : If $n=3$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,2,3),(-1,-2,-3)$.

**Claim 6** : If $n=4$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,1,2,4),(-1,1,-2,-2)$.

**Claim 7** : If $n=5$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(-1,-1,1,1,k),(1,1,1,2,5),(-1,-1,-1,-2,-5),(1,1,1,3,3),(-1,-1,-1,-3,-3),(1,1,2,2,2),(-1,-1,-2,-2,-2)$ where $k$ is any non-zero integer.

**Claim 8** : If $n=6$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)=(1,1,1,1,2,6),(-1,-1,1,1,2,2),(-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,2),(-1,-1,-1,1,-2,-4)$

---

I'll use the following ideas to prove the claims.

- We may suppose that $|a_1|\le |a_2|\le\cdots \le |a_n|$.
- $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\le n$.
  **Proof** : $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg||a_n|=\bigg|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\bigg|\le \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_j|\le n|a_n|$
- For $n\ge 3$, $|a_1|=|a_2|=\cdots =|a_m|=1$ and $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=m+1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\le n$ where $m=n-1-\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor$.
  **Proof** : Suppose that $|a_m|\ge 2$. Then, $n\ge \displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\ge \bigg|\prod_{j=m}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\ge 2^{n-m}=2^{1+\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}\gt 2^{\log_2 n}=n$ which is a contradiction.
- $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=m+1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\le n-m+\frac{m}{|a_{n-1}|}$
  **Proof** : $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=m+1}^{n}a_j\bigg|\le m+(n-m)|a_n|$, so $\displaystyle\bigg|\prod_{j=m+1}^{n-1}a_j\bigg|\le n-m+\frac{m}{|a_n|}\le n-m+\frac{m}{|a_{n-1}|}$
- $m+\displaystyle\sum_{j=m+1}^{n}a_j=\prod_{j=m+1}^{n}a_j\pmod 2$
  **Proof** : This is because $a_1\equiv a_2\equiv \cdots\equiv a_m\equiv 1\pmod 2$.
- If $a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1\not=0$, then $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{|a_{n-1}|}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|a_j|\le\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\le 1+\frac{1}{|a_{n-1}|}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|a_j|$
  **Proof** : $|a_{n-1}|\le |a_n|=\bigg|\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-1}}{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1}\bigg|\le\dfrac{|a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots +|a_{n-1}|}{|a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1|}\implies |a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1|\le\frac{|a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots +|a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n-1}|}$
- If $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)=(b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n)$ is a solution where $n$ is odd, then $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)=(-b_1,-b_2,\cdots, -b_n)$ is a solution.
- If $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)=(b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n)$ is a solution, then $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_{n+4})=(-1,-1,1,1,b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n)$ is a solution.

---

In the following, I'm going to prove the claims.

**Claim 1** : If $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then the equation has infinitely many non-zero integer solutions.

**Proof** : $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=(\underbrace{-1,-1,\cdots,-1}_{\frac{n-1}{2}},\underbrace{1,1,\cdots, 1}_{\frac{n-1}{2}},k)$ is a solution where $k$ is any non-zero integer.

**Claim 2** : If $n\not\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then the equation has only finitely many non-zero integer solutions.

**Proof** : We have $a_n(a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1)=a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-1}$. Suppose that $a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1=0$. Then, $|a_1|=|a_2|=\cdots =|a_{n-1}|=1$. Let $A$ be the number of $j(1\le j\le n-1)$ such that $a_j=1$. Let $B$ be the number of $j(1\le j\le n-1)$ such that $a_j=-1$. Since $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-1}=0$, we see that $B$ is even and that $A=B$. It follows that $n-1=A+B=2B\equiv 0\pmod 4$ which is a contradiction. Since $a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1\not=0$, we have $|a_{n-1}|\ge 2$ and $|a_n|=\bigg|\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{n-1}}{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1}\bigg|\le\frac{(n-1)|a_{n-1}|}{|a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}-1|}=\frac{n-1}{|a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-2}-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}|}\le\frac{n-1}{||a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-2}|-\frac{1}{|a_{n-1}|}|}\le \frac{n-1}{\frac 12}=2(n-1)$

**Claim 3** : If $n\ge 3$, then the equation has at least one non-zero integer solutions where at least one $a_i$ is negative.

**Proof** : For odd $n$, $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=(-1,-1,\cdots, -1,-2,-n)$ is a solution. If $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)=(b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n)$ is a solution where $n$ is even, then $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_{n+2})=(-1,1,-b_1,-b_2,\cdots, -b_n)$ is a solution. Since $(a_1,a_2)=(2,2)$ is a solution for $n=2$, the equation for even $n\ge 4$ has at least one non-zero integer solutions where at least one $a_i$ is negative.

**Claim 4** : If $n=2$, the only non-zero integer solution of the equation is $(a_1,a_2)=(2,2)$.

**Proof** : Since $(a_1-1)(a_2-1)=1$ where $a_1,a_2$ are non-zero, we have $(a_1-1,a_2-1)=(1,1)$.

**Claim 5** : If $n=3$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,2,3),(-1,-2,-3)$.

**Proof** : We have $|a_1|=1,|a_2|\le 2+\frac{1}{|a_2|}$ and $|a_2|\le 2$. For $a_1=1$, we have $a_3=1+\frac{2}{a_2-1}$ which implies $a_2=2$ and $a_3=3$.

**Claim 6** : If $n=4$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,1,2,4),(-1,1,-2,-2)$.

**Proof** : We have $|a_1|=1,|a_2|\le 2, |a_2a_3|\le 3+\frac{1}{|a_3|}$ and $1+a_2+a_3+a_4\equiv a_2a_3a_4\pmod 2$. There is only one odd integer in $a_2,a_3$ and $a_4$. So, we have $|a_2|=1$ and $|a_3|=2$. Since we have $-1\le a_1a_2a_3\le 3$, we get $a_1a_2a_3=2$ and $|a_1+a_2+a_3|\ge 2$.

**Claim 7** : If $n=5$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(-1,-1,1,1,k),(1,1,1,2,5),(-1,-1,-1,-2,-5),(1,1,1,3,3),(-1,-1,-1,-3,-3),(1,1,2,2,2),(-1,-1,-2,-2,-2)$ where $k$ is any non-zero integer.

**Proof** : If $a_1a_2a_3a_4-1=0$, then $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(-1,-1,1,1,k)$ is a solution where $k$ is any non-zero integer. In the following, $a_1a_2a_3a_4-1\not=0$. We have $|a_1|=|a_2|=1,|a_3|\le 2$ and $|a_3a_4|\le 3+\frac{2}{|a_4|}$. 
(case 1) If $|a_3|=1$, then $|a_4|\le 3$. 
For $|a_4|=1$, $a_5=\pm 1$. 
For $|a_4|=2$, since $-\frac 32\le a_1a_2a_3a_4\le \frac 72$, we have $a_1a_2a_3a_4=2$ and $|a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4|\ge 2$.
For $|a_4|=3$, since $-1\le a_1a_2a_3a_4\le 3$, we have $a_1a_2a_3a_4=3$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=\pm 6$ since $6=(3-1)\times 3\le |a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4|\le |a_1|+|a_2|+|a_3|+|a_4|=6$
(case 2) If $|a_3|=2$, then $|a_4|=2$. Since $-2\le a_1a_2a_3a_4\le 4$, we have $a_1a_2a_3a_4=4$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=\pm 6$.

**Claim 8** : If $n=6$, the only non-zero integer solutions of the equation are $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)=(1,1,1,1,2,6),(-1,-1,1,1,2,2),(-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,2),(-1,-1,-1,1,-2,-4)$

**Proof** : We have $|a_1|=|a_2|=|a_3|=1,|a_4|\le 2,|a_4a_5|\le 3+\frac{3}{|a_5|}$ and $1+a_4+a_5+a_6\equiv a_4a_5a_6\pmod 2$. There is only one odd integer in $a_4,a_5$ and $a_6$.
(case 1) If $|a_4|=1$, then $|a_5|=2$. For $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5=2$, we have $|a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5|\ge 2$. For $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5=-2$, we have $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=\pm 6$. 
(case 2) If $|a_4|=2$, then $|a_5|=2$. Since $-\frac 52\le a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5\le\frac 92$, we have $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5=4$ and $|a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5|\ge 6$.